# Independent Clause or not

Tags: independent-clauses

Would this be an independent clause:

"This had little noticeable effect on our demographic".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Yes.

Comment: I would say that "This" is the subject of the sentence.

Comment: so a independent clause it is

Comment: ..or **an** independent clause.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to English Language and Usage!

Yes, this is an independent clause: in facts it has a subject, a verb and it has a complete meaning, so, to be clear, if you say this sentence alone, (maybe using a more explicit subject) anyone can understand what you are saying.
Dependent clauses, instead, have a subject and a verb but don’t have a complete meaning, so that if you say them alone they won’t be completely understandable.